# CSS media queries + Javascript - Menu goes off screen on desktop but works well on mobile

Tags: javascript, css

I’m having problems with CSS media queries and a UL tag. 
Basically I have two menus (left and right) and a search bar. 
When the user activates the menus, the menus slide from the edge of the screen as they supposed to. 
The menus will slide back when the search bar is clicked/tapped. This works as intended on mobile, but the right menu goes off screen on the desktop version.

What am I doing wrong here? 
Could you please shed some light in here?

here's what I got:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
</head>
<body>

<div id = "container">

<div id="left-menu"onclick ="list1()" class ="dropbtn">menu </div>
<div id = "left-list" class="dropdown-content">
<ul>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div id="find" onclick ="clear()"><input ="search" id="myInput"  placeholder="Search!"></input></div>




<div class="mob-menu">
<a href="#" class="icon" onclick="max()">&#9776;</a>
<div id="right-menu">
<ul>

<li><a href="#">Top level menu</a>
<div class="m2">
<ul>
<li><p>List item</p></li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Top level menu 2</a>
<ul>
<div class="m3">
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width:450px) and (min-width:321px){



/*Main container*/
#container{width:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,1); height:auto; position:fixed;     top:0%; left:0%; float:left; z-index:3; user-select:none;  }


/*Left menu */
#left-menu{font-size:8vw; color:white;}
#left-list ul{  width:97%;  height:140vw; list-style-type:none;  padding:0px  0px 3% 0px;  overflow:auto;}
#left-list li{width:97%; height:auto; color:white; }
.dropdown-content{position:absolute; background:rgba(0,0,255,1); overflow:auto; width:102%; height:auto;  float:left; transition:0.2s; transform:translate(-100%, 0%); padding:0% 0% 100% 0%;}


/*right menu - Mobile*/
#right-menu{width:100%; height:auto;  margin:0% 0% 0% 0%; padding:5% 0% 500% 0%; position:absolute; z-index:5;  background:rgba(0,255,0,1); transform:translate(105%, 0%); transition:0.3s; }
#right-menu ul{width:100%; height:auto; list-style-type:none; }
#right-menu li a{text-decoration:none; float:left; text-align:center; width:100%; height:auto; display:block; margin:4% 0% -1% -2%; padding:4% 1% 4% 1%; line-height:1.2; background:rgba(255,255,255,1); color:black; font-weight:bold;  position:relative; left:-9%; font-weight:bold; font-size:4.5vw;}
#right-menu ul li .m3{ float:left; display:none;  width:0%; height:0px; text-align:center;  padding:0% 3% 0% 3%; font-size:4.9vw; font-weight:bold; border-radius:5px; position:relative; margin:2% 0% 0% -25%; transition:0.15s; overflow-x:hidden; }
#right-menu ul li:hover .m3{z-index:5; display:block; width:100%; height:300px; padding:0% 3% 5% 3%; overflow:auto;}
#right-menu ul li .m2{display:none; width:0px; height:0px;  margin:0% 0% 0% 0%; overflow:hidden;}
#right-menu ul li:hover .m2{display:block; height:auto; width:97%; margin:-10.15% 0% 15% 0%; padding:2% 0% 0% 0%; position:relative; left:-10%; top:0vw;}

.mob-menu a{font-weight:bold; font-size:10vw; float:right; text-decoration:none; text-align: center;  margin:-12% 0% 0% 0%; color:white; }


/*Search bar*/
#find input{position:fixed; left:11.5%; top:1.7vw; width:60vw; height:auto; background:rgba(255,255,255,1); font-weight:bold; text-align:center;  font-size:4.9vw; border-radius:5px; border:1px solid rgba(80,80,80,0.2); padding:1% 0% 1% 0%; color:black; box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3); margin:0% 0% 0% 10%;}
#find input:hover{box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); }
#find input:focus{box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }}


@media screen and (max-width:1920px) and (min-width:1777px){


/*Main container*/
#container{width:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,1); height:auto; position:fixed; top:0%; left:0%; float:left; z-index:3; user-select:none; padding-bottom:2%;}


/*Left menu */
#left-menu{font-size:3vw;  width:8%; height:auto; margin:0% 0% -2% 0%; color:white;}
#left-list ul{  width:97%;  height:140vw; list-style-type:none;  padding:0px 0px 3% 0px;  overflow:auto;}
#left-list li{width:97%; height:auto; color:white; }
.dropdown-content{position:absolute; background:rgba(0,0,255,1); overflow:auto; width:102%; height:auto;  float:left; transition:0.2s; transform:translate(-100%, 0%); padding:0% 0% 100% 0%; margin:2% 0% 0% 0%; }


/*right menu - Mobile*/
#right-menu{width:100%; position:fixed; transform:translate(52%, -90%); z-index:3; transition:2s;}
#right-menu ul{ width:90%; height:auto; margin:0.0% 0% 0% 0%; padding:0% 0% 0% 0%; float:left; list-style-type:none;}
#right-menu li a{width:11.5%; height:auto; display:block; float:left; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; color:black; font-weight:bold; font-size:0.8vw;  background:rgba(255,255,255,1); margin:21.0% 1.5% 1% 0%; padding:0.85% 0% 0.85% 0%; border:1px solid rgba(80,80,80,0.2); border-radius:5px; float:left; }
#right-menu ul li .m3{background:rgba(0,255,0,1); border-radius:5px; float:left; display:none;  width:30%; height:auto; margin:-1.0% 0% 1% 0%; text-align:center;  padding:3% 3% 5% 3%; font-size:0.9vw; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid rgba(80,80,80,0.2); border-radius:10px; position:absolute; left:10.5%; z-index:1; overflow:auto; }
#right-menu ul li:hover .m3{display:block; height:auto;  }
#right-menu li a:hover{background:rgba(0,0,0,1); color:white;}
#right-menu ul li .m2{background:rgba(0,255,0,1); border-radius:5px; float:left; display:none;  width:30%; height:auto; margin:21.5% 0% 1% 0%; text-align:center;  padding:3% 3% 5% 3%;font-size:0.9vw; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid rgba(80,80,80,0.2); border-radius:10px; position:absolute; left:-0.5%; z-index:1; overflow:auto;}
#right-menu ul li:hover .m2{display:block; height:auto;}



.mob-menu a{display:none;}


/*Search bar*/
#find input{ position:fixed; left:11.5%; top:0vw; width:20vw; height:auto; background:rgba(255,255,255,1); font-weight:bold; text-align:center;  font-size:1vw; border-radius:5px; border:1px solid rgba(80,80,80,0.2);  padding:1% 0% 1% 0%; color:black; box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3); margin:0% 0% 0% 10%;}
#find input:hover{box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); }
#find input:focus{box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }}
```

JavaScript

```
function max(){
var x= document.getElementById('right-menu');
    if (x.style.transform==="translate(0%, 0%)"){
        x.style.transform="translate(105%, 0%)"  
    } else {
        x.style.transform="translate(0%, 0%)";}}


var input = document.getElementById('find');
var message = document.getElementById('right-menu');
var msg = document.getElementById('left-list');
input.addEventListener('focusin', function() {
message.style.transform = "translate(100%, 0%)" });
input.addEventListener('focusin', function() {
msg.style.transform = "translate(-100%, 0%)" });



/*Menu*/
function list1(){
var r= document.getElementById('left-list');
if (r.style.transform==="translate(0%, 0%)"){
        r.style.transform="translate(-100%, 0%)"  
    } else {
        r.style.transform="translate(0%, 0%)";}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is quite good, but you are wrapping too much in the media queries.

It is a good practice to write the first part of your css outside of media queries, focusing on things that will apply to all screen resolutions.

I created a code pen with your code and modified it a bit: https://codepen.io/vic3685/pen/xWdZzM

I didn't clean up your old css, just modified a few things at the very top:

```
body, html {margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#container{width:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,1); height:auto;color: white; }

/*Left menu */
#left-menu{
  color:white;
}

#left-list ul{  
    width:100%;
  list-style-type:none;          
  padding:0px  0px 3% 0px;  
  overflow:auto;

}
#left-list li{
  width:97%; height:auto; color:white; }

.dropdown-content{position:absolute; background:rgba(0,0,255,1);
```

overflow:auto; width:102%; height:auto;  float:left; transition:0.2s; transform:translate(-100%, 0%); padding:0% 0% 20px 0%;}

```
@media (min-width: 451px) {
  #left-list {
    width:200px;
    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 50px; 
  } 
  #right-menu {
    width: 200px; 
    position: absolute; right: 0; top: 50px; 
    height:auto;  margin:0% 0% 0% 0%; padding:5% 0% 500% 0%; position:absolute; z-index:5;  background:rgba(0,255,0,1); transform:translate(105%, 0%); transition:0.3s; 
    transition:0.15s;
  }
  #left-list ul {padding-left: 30px; } 
  #left-menu, #find, .mob-menu {float: left; height: 50px;}
  .mob-menu {float:  right;}
  .mob-menu > a {display: block; text-align: right; }
  #container:after {
    content: ""; 
    display: block;
    clear: both; 
  }
}
```

My changes included: 
- extracting some code outside of media queries.
- creating a media query for anything > 450px which you had no css for previously.

To get the menus to show in from the side, you need to position them at the sides, which is why I used `float` and a `clear:both` after that (see css for `#container:after`). You could use flexbox instead, but I didn't know what browser support you need. 
Additionally, I added position:absolute to the content of the menus, in case you want them to be independent of the content in between.

You'll have to polish the styles yourself, but I think this should get you started.

Comment: Victoria 
Thank you for the help! 
The CSS needed a bit of cleaning.
That's not quite of what I wanted to achieve.

On my original post I have two media queries: one for mobile and one for desktops/laptops. I have more media queries, but I only included these two for simplicity. 
The desktop version has two drop down menus on the right and they work well. I also have another menu on the left; it's activated by pressing the menu button on the top left. That also works well.

Comment: I have a similar setup on the mobile version but the drop down menu on the right is hidden and is activated by clicking the hamburger menu. 

I have a search box on the top -  middle of the page.
When the left and or right menu is visible, it will disappear when you click or tap on the search box - This works as intended. 

Now here's the problem: 

On the desktop version if you click the search bar, the right menu will go off screen. I don't have this problem with the mobile version. 

How can we resolve this?